# How to get a list of columns on which the sort key is applied in a table using aws redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to see, which columns of a table have the Sort key (Compound / Interleaved) applied.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_REDSHIFT_COLUMNS.html) where we can filter the table and see sort keys respectively.

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, distkey, sortkey 
FROM svv_redshift_columns
WHERE schema_name = 'SCHEMA_NAME_HERE'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_NAME_HERE'
AND isnull(sortkey, 0) != 0
ORDER BY sortkey
```